# Why the orbit is of dimension $12$?

Tags: group-theory, algebraic-geometry, representation-theory, group-actions

Let $SL_3$ acts on the variety consisting of all nilpotent $3$ by $3$ matrices over $\mathbb{C}$ by conjugation. Let $S_p$ be the orbit of the matrix $$ a=\left( \begin{matrix} 0 & 1 & 0  \\ 0 & 0 & 1 \\ 0 & 0 & 0 \end{matrix} \right). $$ Why the orbit $S_p$ over $\mathbb{R}$ is of dimension $12$?

I think that $S_p$ consisting of all matrices $g a g^{-1} $, $g \in SL_3$. But how to show that $S_p$ over $\mathbb{R}$ is of dimension $12$? Thank you very much.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By orbit-stabilizer, the dimension of the orbit should be the dimension of the group minus the dimension of the stabilizer, so we should compute the dimension of the stabilizer. Suppose

$$\begin{pmatrix} a & b & c \\ d & e & f \\ g & h & i\end{pmatrix} \begin{pmatrix} 0 & 1 & 0 \\ 0 & 0 & 1 \\ 0 & 0 & 0\end{pmatrix} = \begin{pmatrix} 0 & 1 & 0 \\ 0 & 0 & 1 \\ 0 & 0 & 0\end{pmatrix} \begin{pmatrix} a & b & c \\ d & e & f \\ g & h & i\end{pmatrix}.$$

Multiplying the matrices, this tells us

$$\begin{pmatrix} 0 & a & b \\ 0 & d & e \\ 0 & g & h \end{pmatrix} = \begin{pmatrix} d & e & f \\ g & h & i \\ 0 & 0 & 0 \end{pmatrix}.$$

Therefore $d,g,h=0$ and $a=e=i$ and $b=f$. So a stabilizing matrix looks like

$$\begin{pmatrix}a & b & c \\ 0 & a & b \\ 0 & 0 & a\end{pmatrix}.$$

In order to be in ${\rm SL}_3$ it must satisfy $a^3=1$, so $a$ is a cube root of unity. This leaves two degrees of freedom ($b$ and $c$), so the stabilizer has complex dimension $2$. The group ${\rm SL}_3(\Bbb C)$ has complex dimension equal to $3^2-1=8$. Therefore the orbit has complex dimension $8-2=6$, which means it has real dimension equal to $2\cdot 6=12$.

Comment: thank you very much. Why the dimension of the orbit is not $8/2=4$ but $8-2=6$?

Comment: @LJR Well, consider the subspace $\Bbb C^m\subset\Bbb C^n$ when $m<n$. If we look at the coset space $\Bbb C^n/\Bbb C^m$, do you think the dimension is $n/m$? Of course not, it's $n-m$. Same idea here, except the spaces can be curved.

Comment: thank you very much. I think that for vector spaces we have $\dim V/W = \dim V - \dim W$, where $W$ is a subspace of $V$. But it seems that for groups, we have $[G: H]=|G|/|H|$, where $H$ is a subgroup of $G$.

Comment: @LJR we are computing dimension, not cardinality. Can't you **visualize** the situation? Having a visual understanding of the geometry is pretty important. What happens if you look at $\Bbb C^n/\Bbb C^m$ and then bend the spaces around the origin, does bending the spaces change their dimension? The partition of a lie group $G$ into cosets of a lie subgroup $H$ is a *foliation* of $G$.

Comment: Consider the invertible quaternions $\Bbb H^\times$ and the subgroup $\Bbb R^\times$ as real manifolds; do you think the real dimension of $\Bbb H^\times/\Bbb R^\times$ is the same as $\Bbb H^\times$, as would be predicted by simply dividing the dimensions? Or consider projective spaces. If we take $\Bbb R^n\setminus\{0\}$, whose real dimension is $n$, and partition it into the $1$-dimensional subspaces (minus $0$), does the resulting projective space have real dimension $n$? Think about the fact that projective points correspond to antipodal points on the sphere of dimension $n-1$.

Comment: Or consider tangent spaces; their dimension matches the manifold. We know $T_p{\cal N}\subseteq T_p{\cal M}$ if $\cal N\subseteq M$. If we foliate a space $\cal M$ into copies of some submanifold $\cal N$, then tangent spaces $T_p(\cal M/N)$ can be identified with $T_p{\cal M}/T_p{\cal N}$, and one can compute the dimensions knowing these are vector spaces. Picture an onion of layered $2$-spheres in $\Bbb R^3$ parametrized by a ray: the tangent space of a sphere at a point is the tangent plane, and the tangent space of the point in the *quotient* manifold is the normal vector!